# UITableView with header view not scrolling to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with a header. There is a 'TOP' button on the view to scroll the table view to top. The issue is on click of TOP button, the `UITableView` is scrolling upto the first section and not till the `UITableView` header. I am using the below line of code :

```
 [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0 )];
```

I need to scroll the `UITableView` to the top so that `HeaderView` is also visible.

Please let me know if any other information is required on this.

Comment: try using ` tableView scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.frame.size.height), animated: true)`

Answer (score 2):

It's better to not to assume that top point is `CGPointZero` (content insets)
Try this code:

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, -tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ive had this same problem with the `UITableView`. I had mine in the main storyboard my fix was just shrinking the top of the tableview down like a fifth of the page so the tableview wasn't touching the top. Id say do that or try making the 'y' coordinate a number other than 0.